# Conway's Game of Life (follow-up)

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, python-3.x, game-of-life

I asked for a [review of my code](/q/82657), and after making the suggested changes I feel that now the OOP version is clearer in its meaning and overall the code looks cleaner.

```
"""Object oriented implementaition of Conway's Game of life"""
import random
import time
import os

class GameOfLife():
    FILE_NAME = "grid.txt"
    ROWS = 22
    COLS = 62
    DELAY = 0.2
    GENERATIONS = 200

    def __init__(self, rows=ROWS, cols=COLS, delay=DELAY,from_file=False, \
                num_generations=GENERATIONS, alive_cell="*", dead_cell="."):
        """
        Initializes a GameOfLife Object with the provided values
        """
        self.generations = num_generations
        self.alive_cell = alive_cell
        self.dead_cell = dead_cell
        if from_file:
            self.cur_gen = self.read_grid()
        else:
            self.cur_gen = self.init_grid()
       self.rows = len(self.cur_gen)
        self.cols = len(self.cur_gen[0])

    def read_grid(self):
        """
        Reads a given grid from a text file and sanitizes it to be used with the
        script.
        """
        array = []
        with open("grid.txt", "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                temp = []
                for char in line:
                    if char == "*":
                        temp.append(1)
                    elif char == ".":
                        temp.append(0)
                array += [temp]

        for i in range(len(array)):
            for j in range(len(array[0])):
                if (i == 0 or j == 0 or (i == len(array) - 1) or (j == len(array[0]) - 1)):
                    array[i][j] = -1
        return array


    def init_grid(self,rows=ROWS, cols=COLS):
        """
        Returns an array filled with random alive and dead cells of the given
        dimensions
        """
        array = []
        for i in range(rows):
            single_row = []
            for j in range(cols):
                if(i == 0 or j == 0 or (i == rows - 1) or ( j == cols - 1 )):
                    single_row.append(-1)
                else:
                    ran = random.randint(0,3)
                    if ran == 0:
                        single_row.append(1)
                    else:
                        single_row.append(0)
            array.append(single_row)
        return array

    def process_next_gen(self):
        """
        Iterates over each element of the current generation and processes their
        neighbors.
        """
        for i in range(1, self.rows-1):
            for j in range(1, self.cols-1):
                self.next_gen[i][j] = self.process_neighbors(i, j)

    def process_neighbors(self, x, y):
        """
        Returns the value for a given cell in the next generation

        Keyword arguments:
        x -- row coordinate of the current cell
        y -- column coordinate of the current cell
        """
        neighbor_count = 0

        # range() method in pyhton is exclusive
        for i in range(x-1, x+2):
            for j in range(y-1, y+2):
                if not(i == x and j == y):
                    if self.cur_gen[i][j] != -1:
                        # The count is incremented by whatever value is contained by the
                        # neighboring cell.
                        neighbor_count += self.cur_gen[i][j]

        # Checking the 4 rules of game of life.
        if self.cur_gen[x][y] == 1 and neighbor_count < 2:
            return 0
        if self.cur_gen[x][y] == 1 and neighbor_count > 3:
            return 0
        if self.cur_gen[x][y] == 0 and neighbor_count == 3:
            return 1
        else:
            return self.cur_gen[x][y]

    def print_gen(self, gen):
        """
        Function to handle printing each generation

        Keyword arguments:
        gen -- the number of the current generation
        """
        os.system("clear")
        print("Conway's game of life simulation. Generation : " + str(gen + 1))

        for i in range(self.rows):
            for j in range(self.cols):
                if self.cur_gen[i][j] == -1:
                    print("#", end = " ")
                elif self.cur_gen[i][j] == 1:
                    print(self.alive_cell, end = " ")
                elif self.cur_gen[i][j] == 0:
                    print(self.dead_cell, end = " ")
            print("\n")

    def start_simulation(self):
        """
        This function runs the simulation.
        """
        self.next_gen = self.init_grid(self.rows, self.cols)
        for gen in range(self.generations):
            self.print_gen(gen)
            self.process_next_gen()
            time.sleep(self.DELAY)

            self.cur_gen, self.next_gen = self.next_gen, self.cur_gen
        input("Simulation finished. Press any key to exit")

def user_input(prompt):
    """
    Only accepts an input of values either 1 or 2
    """
    while True:
        try:
            choice = int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter either 1 or 2")
            continue
        if choice < 0 :
            print("Please enter a non negative number")
            continue
        else:
            break
    return choice


def main():
    """
    Single entry point for our module
    """
    print("Select choice : ")
    print("1: Read initial grid from file 'grid.txt'")
    print("2: Generate random grind of size 11X40")

    choice = user_input("Option: ")

    # Reading the grid from file
    if choice == 1:
        simulation = GameOfLife(from_file=True)
        simulation.generations = 2
        simulation.start_simulation()
    elif choice == 2:
        simulation = GameOfLife()
        simulation.dead_cell = " "

        # Unicode for Black Square : http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a0/index.html
        simulation.alive_cell = u"\u25A0"
        simulation.start_simulation()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have a few questions regarding OOP in python though. When are we supposed to use `classmethods`? For example, in this script, when would a `classmethod` be appropriate?

Comment: I already made some suggestions about the use of classmethods in my previous answer (which would replace `simulation = GameOfLife(from_file=True)` with `simulation = GameOfLife.from_file(filename)` and `simulation = GameOfLife()` with `simulation = GameOfLife.from_size(rows, cols)`). If you're unclear on that, you can comment on my answer and I'm happy to expand on that. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/682545/3001761

Comment: *pedant alert* you've defined a "constant" `FILE_NAME`, but then used the string literal `"grid.text"` in `init_grid `.

Answer (score 3):

First off, the line `class GameOfLife():` should be changed to `class GameOfLife:`.

Secondly, using `os.system("clear")` isn't very portable. A more portable method would be `os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")`. If you want re-usability, you can also put this into a function, like this:

```
def clear():
    os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")
```

You also don't need to surround conditions in `if` statements with parentheses. For example `if(i == 0 or j == 0 or (i == rows - 1) or ( j == cols - 1 )):` should be changed to `i (i == 0 or j == 0 or (i == rows - 1) or ( j == cols - 1 ):`.

Finally, some of your variable names aren't so great. For example, `i`, `j`, or `array` are not so great. Variable names like these should be more descriptive and describe what the purpose of the variables are.

Answer (score 3):

First of all I would like to show what a typical GoL code separation in Python looks like :

### Setup

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

printdead, printlive = '-#'
maxgenerations = 3
cellcount = 4,4
celltable = defaultdict(int, {
 (1, 2): 1,
 (1, 3): 1,
 (0, 3): 1,
 } ) # Only need to populate with the keys leading to life
```

### Start States

```
u = universe = defaultdict(int)
u[(1, 0)], u[(1, 1)], u[(1, 2)] = 1, 1, 1
```

### Main loop

```
for i in range(maxgenerations):
```

#### User interface

```
print "\nGeneration %3i:" % ( i, )
for row in range(cellcount[1]):
    print "  ", ''.join(str(universe[(row,col)])
                        for col in range(cellcount[0])).replace(
                            '0', printdead).replace('1', printlive)
```

#### Creating a new Generation

```
nextgeneration = defaultdict(int)
for row in range(cellcount[1]):
    for col in range(cellcount[0]):
        nextgeneration[(row, col)] = celltable[
            ( universe[(row, col)],
              -universe[(row, col)] + sum(universe[(r, c)]
                                         for r in range(row-1, row+2)
                                         for c in range(col-1, col+2) )
            ) ]
universe = nextgeneration
```

### Results

You can run this demo online at : http://www.skulpt.org/ with results :

```
Generation   0:
   ----
   ###-
   ----
   ----

Generation   1:
   -#--
   -#--
   -#--
   ----

Generation   2:
   ----
   ###-
   ----
   ----
```

---

Second of all, to

## When are we supposed to use classmethods?

Come to a compromise between writing GOD object or no methods at all. A good way is to implement code skeleton that does the minimum and then look what else is required.

In typical OOP language your class is a data structure first. Methods give it's data desired behavior ex: describe how to compare items or serialize them.

### For example, in this script, when would a classmethod be appropriate?

It is important that you reuse existing patterns. For example it would be natural to assume that if you have a GoL universe statespace class and you wanted to print it out, then you could just by doing `print gol`. This is archived with overwriting class method **str**.

```
def __str__(self):
     return "foo"
```

Answer (score 3):

Overall I think your code looks good, but I have some more small suggestions:

- Define constants for "magic" values that appear throughout your
  code, e.g. `ALIVE`, `DEAD` and `INVALID` for 1, 0 and -1 (in the appropriate contexts, of course).
- Be consistent in how you use spaces. For example, you use both `x+1` and `x + 1`, and in one place you put spaces on the inside of parentheses.
- Simplify the nested loops. Some of them are inefficient and some could be written so that the communicate their purpose more clearly:

For example this:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    for j in range(len(array[0])):
        if (i == 0 or j == 0 or (i == len(array) - 1) or (j == len(array[0]) - 1)):
            array[i][j] = -1
```

could be turned into this:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    array[i][0] = -1
    array[i][len(array[0])] = -1

for j in range(len(array[0])):
    array[0][j] = -1
    array[len(array)][j] = -1
```

And this:

```
for i in range(x-1, x+2):
    for j in range(y-1, y+2):
        if not(i == x and j == y):
            if self.cur_gen[i][j] != -1:
                # The count is incremented by whatever value is contained by the
                # neighboring cell.
                neighbor_count += self.cur_gen[i][j]
```

into this:

```
neighbor_count = sum(self.cur_gen[i][j] 
                        for i in [x - 1, x + 1] 
                        for j in [y - 1, y + 1] 
                        if self.cur_gen[i][j] != -1)
```